# Create dynamically multiple panels in a GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout, dynamic, panel

In my GUI, after importing an Excel file, I need to create a variable amount of panels/tabs. The amount depends on the number of rows imported from the Excel file. I need to show the information contained in row in a different panel, with a couple of buttons to move between all the tabs. For example, if the Excel file contains 6 rows:

Field1: user1
Field2: user1Age
<  [1/6]  >

So, I can move through the different panels, by clicking on the arrows:

Field1: user2
Field2: user2Age
<  [2/6]  >

One more consideration: Excel file import is not the only way to get information, it must be possible to manually add information. Therefore, after starting the GUI there must be at least one panel, and if the user decides to import an Excel file, then multiple panels must be created.

I need just a hint to start coding. And of course I am open to other possibilities.

Comment: Instead of creating as many panels as the number of rows (if you have 100 000 rows, it would not be very much scalable), you could create a reusable panel on which you can set the row and update all fields accordingly. Pressing the "Next" or "Previous" button would simply then fetch the next or previous row in the excel sheet

Comment: Thanks Guillaume Polet, I have applied your idea and it is already working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code that should get you started (you will need to reorganize a bit the code). Although there are 1000 dummy users, it only uses a single panel to display the information:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestMultiplePanels {

    private final UserList userList;

    private User currentUser;

    private JTextField name;

    private JTextField age;

    private JTextField index;

    private JButton prev;

    private JButton next;

    public TestMultiplePanels(UserList userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel userPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel userInfoPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel ageLabel = new JLabel("Age");
        name = new JTextField(30);
        age = new JTextField(5);
        index = new JTextField(5);
        index.setEditable(false);
        prev = new JButton("<");
        prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setCurrentUser(userList.previous(currentUser));
            }
        });
        next = new JButton(">");
        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setCurrentUser(userList.next(currentUser));
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbcLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        GridBagConstraints gbcField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcField.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbcField.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        userInfoPanel.add(nameLabel, gbcLabel);
        userInfoPanel.add(name, gbcField);
        userInfoPanel.add(ageLabel, gbcLabel);
        userInfoPanel.add(age, gbcField);
        buttonPanel.add(prev);
        buttonPanel.add(index);
        buttonPanel.add(next);
        userPanel.add(userInfoPanel);
        userPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setCurrentUser(userList.getUsers().get(0));
        frame.add(userPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setCurrentUser(User user) {
        currentUser = user;
        name.setText(user.getUserName());
        age.setText(String.valueOf(user.getAge()));
        index.setText(user.getIndex() + "/" + userList.getCount());
        next.setEnabled(userList.hasNext(user));
        prev.setEnabled(userList.hasPrevious(user));
    }

    public static class UserList {
        private List<User> users;
        private List<User> unmodifiableUsers;

        public UserList() {
            super();
            this.users = load();
            unmodifiableUsers = Collections.unmodifiableList(users);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return users.size();
        }

        public List<User> getUsers() {
            return unmodifiableUsers;
        }

        private List<User> load() {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<TestMultiplePanels.User>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setUserName("User " + (i + 1));
                user.setAge((int) (Math.random() * 80));
                user.setIndex(i + 1);
                users.add(user);
            }
            return users;
        }

        public boolean hasNext(User user) {
            return user.getIndex() - 1 < users.size();
        }

        public boolean hasPrevious(User user) {
            return user.getIndex() > 1;
        }

        public User next(User user) {
            if (hasNext(user)) {
                return users.get(user.getIndex());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public User previous(User user) {
            if (hasPrevious(user)) {
                return users.get(user.getIndex() - 2);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class User {
        private String userName;
        private int age;
        private int index;

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final UserList userList = new UserList();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestMultiplePanels testMultiplePanels = new TestMultiplePanels(userList);
                testMultiplePanels.initUI();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the panels dynamically using an ArrayList, which I think is flexible enough for that and easily manageable. To handle panels display, you can use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java). Hope it helps

```
   ArrayList<JPanel> panelGroup = new ArrayList<JPanel>();    
        for (int i=0;i<numberOfPanelsToCreate;i++){ 
                panelGroup.add(new JPanel());
   }
```

Comment: But I think you'll have performance issues/side-effects with this kind of code...

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick B., I have decided to reuse a panel by adding two buttons and writing a method to update the table model.